# SQL choose a row until a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as follow:

First table shows all the orders:

```
table PURCHASE_ORDER:
ID   UNIT_#    PRICE   ITEM_KEY
1      2         3        1
2      3         2.5      1
3      1         3        1
```

Second table shows available number of the units in the inventory:

```
table INVENTORY:
ID    ITEM_KEY    UNIT_AVAILABLE
1        1            5
2        2            7
```

Now the question is how to calculate the average cost of the items in the inventory. For example for item 1:

Average cost for item 1 = ((1*3)+(3*2.5)+(1*3))/5
 /* the total number of the items in the inventory is 5 (1+3+1 = 5) */

Is there any way to do this in pure microsoft SQL?

Comment: What is Unit_#? Is that the amount of units you bought at that price?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what it is

Comment: Yes it can be done. Do you mind explaining each number's column name here? ((1*3)+(3*2.5)+(1*3))/5... Thanks...Like the 1st 1 is Item_Key or etc.

Comment: That just gives me the average cost of all the purchases. I need just up to the number I have in the inventory based on the number of the units I bought, i.e. 2.7 .

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL 2012.if compatible with 2008 even better

Comment: Shouldn't the calculation be `((2*3)+(3*2.5)+(1*3))/6`? The total `UNIT_#` is `6` made up of quantities 2, 3 and 1. But seem to think it's 1, 3, 1... totaling 5. Where are those numbers 1, 3 and 1 coming from and where does the 5 come from (shouldn't it be 6)? This looks very much like you want a weighted average, which for item #1 would be `((2*3)+(3*2.5)+(1*3))/6` ie $2.75. Can you let me know?

Comment: No, The 5 is coming from the **second table** (inventory). So in total we ordered 6 items. Now in our inventory we have 5 (sold 1 or whatever happened to the other item). So the average cost for the item 1 in our inventory would be the average costs of the items we have (latest ordered up to we meet the inventory).

Answer (score 1):

You need a cumulative sum.  Let me assume you are using SQL Server 2012, because it simplifies the code.

```
select po.item_key,
       (sum(case when po.cumunits <= i.unit_available then po.[unit#]*po.price
                 when po.cumunits > i.unit_available and
                      po.cumunits - [unit#] < i.unit_available
                 then (i.unit_available - (po.cumunits - [unit#]))*po.price
                 else 0
            end) /
        sum(case when po.cumunits <= i.unit_available then po.[unit#]
                 when po.cumunits > i.unit_available and
                      po.cumunits - [unit#] < i.unit_available
                 then (i.unit_available - (po.cumunits - [unit#]))
                 else 0
            end)
      ) as avgprice
from (select po.*, sum([unit#]) over (partition by item_key order by id) as cumunits
      from purchase_order po
     ) po join
     inventory i
     on po.item_key = i.item_key
group po.item_key;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you need to use a correlated subquery for the cumulative sum.

Comment: This looks what I want. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: This one didn't work,I think I will use some other non data oriented language to do it

Answer (score 0):

Based on how the tables are setup

```
select po.*
     , i.*
     , AvgPrice = sum(po.[UNIT_#] * po.Price) over (partition by po.item_key)
                  /
                  i.unit_available
  from PURCHASE_ORDER po
       inner join INVENTORY i
         on (po.ITEM_KEY = i.ITEM_KEY);
```

should do the trick